# Using a JavaScript function instead of a URL for filling a Flexigrid

Tags: json, flexigrid

Is it possible to use a JavaScript function instead of a URL to fill a [Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info)?
The function I want to use returns a JSON object.

Comment: Probably yes, but please link flexgrid to sure what we deal with.

Comment: Searching for the same, please add answer when u found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it.

You can call : FlexiGrid.flexAddData(myData);

```
var myRows = getRows();
var myData = { total: myRows.length , page: 1, rows: myRows  };    
flexiGrid.flexAddData(eval(myData));
```

The rows in myRows have to be normal flexigrid rows.

Comment: rohitszone's comment: "Could you Please post the function you have written to getRows() to have JSON Object ?? Also what do I mention for url parameter inside flexigrid call ?? Answers might be quite simple, am very new."

Comment: Hi Peter,
getRows() has to return a JSON object like this:
function getRows(){
 return {[{"id":"1","cell":["row1, cell1","row1, cell2"]},{"id":"2","cell":["row2, cell1","row2, cell2"]}]};
}

You can leave the url parameter empty.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do that. Just call the java script method using from flex apis that return JSON object...

1. write a JS method that return JSON object,
2. List item from flex application call JS method using ExternalInterface.call(JSmethod) api (for more detail please refer to [flex doc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=19_External_Interface_09.html))
3. List item create a ArrayCollection object by parsing JSON object using JSON.decode()
4. List item set ArrayCollection object as the data source of the Grid.

Comment: The link is pointing to 'Programming ActionScript 3.0' with javascript example